# Is this question a good match for programmers.stackexchange.com site?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

**Exact Duplicate**: [Is this question a good match for this site?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/is-this-question-a-good-match-for-this-site/)

I've had a question migrated to programmers but I don't think its a good fit for programmers. If I understand the nature of the questions you get there.

[How can you make a cluster run a task only once?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76396/how-can-you-make-a-cluster-run-a-task-only-once)

Should this have been migrated here?

---

I would have thought if the question didn't belong on Stack Overflow it would belong on Server Fault.

I don't think its a subjective question.

---

The reason this question is a duplicate is I asked on programmers and they said this question belongs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks ok to me.  If you look in the [programmers faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), it says:

```
This can include topics such as: 
  Software engineering
  . . .
  Design patterns
  Architecture
  . . .
```

It seems like the question fits under the design patterns or architecture lines in the faq.

I would guess that it was migrated because it's a subjective question, insofar as there isn't a single correct answer, and doesn't deal directly with code.  So it not appropriate for SO, but is on-topic at programmers.

Comment: And yet the P.SE crowd says it belongs here ...

Comment: @drachenstern *Who* says that? People are saying it's not suited for *either* site, which has some merit, but moving it back to Stack Overflow (or re-asking it) isn't really an option.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Sorry, I _meant_ that they were saying it belonged back no SO, not MSO.

Comment: @drachenstern I got that: one person saying he's not entirely sure it should've been migrated is a far cry from the Programmers.SE community saying it belongs on Stack Overflow. It's ostensibly on-topic on Programmers.SE, and its problems on our site aren't due to the content, but due to the manner in which it was asked.